# Uninitialized constant worker class sidekiq rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

I have two servers I'm copying code from one server(A) and then trying to run on another(B).

All my workers on A are working fine. When I run the workers from B I'm getting this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant FeedRefresherFetcher
```

Here's the worker code where error is thrown:

```
class FeedRefresherScheduler
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    Feed.select(:id, :feed_url).find_in_batches(batch_size: 5000) do |feeds|
      arguments = feeds.map do |feed|
        values = feed.attributes.values
        values
      end
      Sidekiq::Client.push_bulk(
        'args'  => arguments,
        'class' => 'FeedRefresherFetcher',
        'queue' => 'feed_refresher_fetcher',
        'retry' => false
      )
    end
  end

end
```

Full trace of the error:

```
2014-09-01T12:41:19Z 14958 TID-qien4 WARN: uninitialized constant FeedRefresherFetcher
2014-09-01T12:41:19Z 14958 TID-qien4 WARN: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `const_get'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `block in constantize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/sidekiq-2.17.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:43:in `block in process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/sidekiq-2.17.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:86:in `do_defer'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/sidekiq-2.17.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:37:in `process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25:in `public_send'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:122:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:322:in `block in handle_message'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:416:in `block in task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:55:in `block in initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:13:in `block in create'
```

Also please note that there is no worker named FeedRefresherFetcher defined in my workers directory. But again the code is same as server A and on server A its working.

I don't have much idea about sidekiq workers. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: when sidekiq try parse this `'class' => 'FeedRefresherFetcher'` it can't constantize your `FeedRefresherFetcher`

Comment: @IS04 what should I do to fix it?

Comment: it looks like you lost this class, just try find it on server `A`

Comment: @IS04 There is no class with this name even on server A.